# How can I perform an Alt key press while my application is loading?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, devexpress, form-load

how to perform alter key press at the time of form loading in vb.net winforms application?

Means when the form's(devExpress's Xtraform) load event is executed that time alt key must be pressed pro-grammatically .
Is it possible? If yes please suggest some code.

thanks.

Comment: *Why* do you need to press the ALT key while the form is loading? I suspect there's a much better solution to your problem than the one you've thought of.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Because i'm using DevExpress tools & i want to develop the shortcut keys to my application . And DevXpress is not providing the direct design time functionality for the button's or other controls. And it only gives when user runs application & presses ALT key at run time. And i don't want to restrict the user for pressing the ALT key during run time. So i decided to press that key pro-grammatically when the form's load event is fired.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If that's the case, DevExpress tools are completely broken. You should not have to do this just to have keyboard shortcuts. The user shouldn't have to reconfigure keyboard shortcuts every time the app starts up, either. You need to fix whatever is wrong with DevExpress. Simulating that the ALT key is being held down while your application is launching is not possible anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to clarify how our controls work.  In fact, you are talking not about button's shortcuts, but accelerator keys which activate a button's action if the Alt+AnyKey is pressed.  To define this accelerator key, the `&` symbol is included in the button's `Text` property.

On all versions of Windows since 2000, the default behavior is to hide the keyboard accelerators, meaning that you won't see this underline in the control's caption. This underlining is only visible when the Alt key is pressed.  If you want that this effect to be always visible, it is necessary to adjust a setting in MS Windows itself, as explained here:

[Always show menu underline (keyboard accelerators)](http://www.vistax64.com/vista-general/42125-always-show-menu-underline-keyboard-accelerators.html)

However, note that the keyboard accelerators will still work, even when the underlines are not visible. The user can trigger the appropriate command by pressing Alt+AnyKey at any time.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for weighing in on this question. Having never used third-party control sets (and not being a particular fan of them in general), I was beginning to think from the description provided that DevExpress controls were just...broken. It's also worth pointing out that the keyboard shortcuts **will still work** even if the underlines are not shown. For example, Alt+F, S will still trigger "&File -> &Save".

Comment: I know what you are saying. But i don't want to restrict the user for doing any settings in the control panel. Is there any other solution for resolving this problem?   thanks.

Comment: @Richa, No, there is no other solution.  I would also like to tell you, that you should not worry.  Your customers should get accustomed to this behavior since this is a standard MS Windows applications behavior.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to send the alt key press pro-grammatically at form load() event? because i'm trying to send this by using `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{ALT}")` but it gives me error as `my application is not handling windows messages`. Do you know anything related to this?

Answer (score 0):

Use in the form load section

```vb
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%")
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("Esc")
```

Problem solved!